# Microsoft Teams go to a conversation using a deeplink

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

we have an app for MS Teams which users can start a conversation and send messages to. The app does some processing and returns the response back. I am looking for the ability to open an precreated conversation using a link. I have needed information like conversation id etc. How do i create a link that can be used for this navigation?

To be more specific this doc is not helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat

The link i need is for the conversation. Currently it is possible to manually copy that link by right clicking on any conversation and use "Copy link". Is there a way to get it or generate it when user creates the conversation. A sample link copied from looks like below

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:a0a0088174a644cb91409f4d8f79d888@thread.tacv2/1612324568748?tenantId=04e930f3-0866-4a6d-b07c-a4737e8f9865&groupId=087bf290-deb5-4790-b159-bf86914765b4&parentMessageId=1612324568748&teamName=Sales%20Team&channelName=FlashCX%20Sales&createdTime=1612324568748
```

So trying to see if i can either get this the URL using apis or can generate with the parts involved

Comment: You can create a deeplink to any chat, which will redirect the user to the specific chat with a message. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) for more info?

Comment: this requires me to specify users and will create a new chat. what i am looking for is to navigate to an existing conversation for which i have the conversation id.

Comment: When you mention user mail id , if that user has already has conversation then it will redirect to the same chat, if conversation does not exits it will create new conversation.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT the conversation is created in the channel. so there is no define set of users and there can be any number of users in the channel. So what you are suggesting is not feasible it seems. We need the conversation link which it seems is available in the teams UI. i have added more details in the question. Please see if that clarifies and can help me get a better solution

Answer (score 0):

@Moblize - Currently you can create Deep-link to chat for particular conversation. You cannot create a link which will redirect to a particular message in channel. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) for info.

Comment: Thanks for response, even direct linking to chat is very much useless in our situation as it requires to manually specify all the users. Ability to navigate using chat id or conversation id would be very desirable

Comment: also notice that this is available in Teams UI using the option "get link" so seems MS anyhow doing it internally